# Detect class is kotlin or java

Tags: java, kotlin

My lots of library is in java. And some of them, I need to know type of the class. Is there any way out in java?

Is a class Java or Kotlin?

Comment: Interfaces, probably

Comment: Why would you want to know?

Comment: @wilx I write logcat output with line anchor, I need to know for putting ".java" or ".kt"

Answer (score 4):

Classes generated by the Kotlin compiler have a kotlin.Metadata annotation that you can read by reflection: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-metadata/

Comment: so, how to get them from java?

Comment: `anObject.getClass().getAnnotation(kotlin.Metadata.class)`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might employ multiple heuristics and approaches to get the correct source file name. One might be reading the `.class` file directly and getting the name of the source file from there:

```
    ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(this.getClass().getName()); // Just so that we have some class to read here.
    ClassNode cn = new ClassNode();
    cr.accept(cn, ClassReader.SKIP_FRAMES | ClassReader.SKIP_CODE);
    LOGGER.info("class {} source file: {}", cn.name, cn.sourceFile);
```

The above uses [ASM](https://asm.ow2.io/versions.html).

Another might be a fall back to something like the `@kotlin.Metadata` annotation.